# multiple regression using a constant predictor

Tags: regression, modeling

I've been using multiple liner regression with several predictors and I was also examining the importance of each one with the R package relaimpo. Now, I'd like to modify the model introducing two more predictors. My problem is that both are constant and I am not sure  how to address the regression in those cases (or whether it would be OK). I am interested in the effect of those predictors.
Although, I also think that it won't be possible to use the same function to look at the importance (I would get the error: system is computationally singular reciprocal condition number).
I'd really appreciate any suggestion or explanation about my issue.

Comment: You want to make predictions based on a variable that has the same value for every observation; is that correct?

Comment: Look at this way: you want to find the effect of being male on wages. To answer this question, you would need a sample of wages for both males and females. If you have a variable which is constant for all observations, then you have nothing to compute differences over, nothing to compare against. It is not of question of this being "okay", or "bad practice", but simply that your are asking for something which is completely impossible.

Comment: Another way to see why @repmat is right is to note that you *already* included constant predictors in your original model, because it had an "intercept" or "constant" term in it.  Adding more such terms provides no new information--and that's why the software issues that error.  (Gentler software will just throw out your redundant variables and proceed with the calculation.)

Comment: A variable that doesn't change at all is always useless.

Comment: Thanks, then  I guess it doesn't make much sense to use it in the model. Thanks anyway for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have two predictors which have the same value for all observations, and then

> I am interested in the effect of those predictors

Then, the only solution is to somehow (maybe by an experiment) obtain new data where this predictors do not have the same value for all the observations.